# sass palettes not working in a mixin

Tags: sass

Someone can explain to me why my background colour in that mixin with palettes is not working properly?

```
// UI Colors

// Call the color palette modifiers in color values
@function palette($palette, $shade: 'base') {
  @return map-get(map-get($color-palettes, $palette), $shade);
}

$white: #fff;
$black: #0b0b0b;
$grey : #797e83;

$color-palettes: (
    grey: (
        xx-light : lighten($grey, 43%),
        x-light  : lighten($grey, 35%),
        light    : lighten($grey, 12%),
        base     : $grey,
        dark     : darken($grey, 8%),
        x-dark   : darken($grey, 16%)
    ),
    black: (
        light : lighten($black, 10%),
        base  : $black,
        dark  : darken($black, 10%)
    )
);

$ui-colors: (
  sidebar-close : $white,
  filter-close  : $white,
  search-close  : palette(black, dark),
);

// Generate modifier color classes
@mixin bg-colors($map) {
  @each $theme, $color in $map {
    &-#{$theme} {
      background-color: $color;
    }
  }
}

.btn {
  @include colors($ui-colors);

}
```

result:

```
.btn-search-open {
    background-color: invalid not working;
}
```

So when is rendered my bg does not apear someone know what it is happening?

Comment: your mixin name is `bg-colors` not `colors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function `palette` that returns a key value from map.

Sassmeister [demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/92f9448a2f4bbe31949fe59bf94ee90b).

Scss:

```
$white : #fff;
$black : #0b0b0b;
$grey  : #797e83;

$color-palettes: (
    grey: (
        xx-light : lighten($grey, 43%),
        x-light  : lighten($grey, 35%),
        light    : lighten($grey, 12%),
        base     : $grey,
        dark     : darken($grey, 8%),
        x-dark   : darken($grey, 16%)
    ),
    black: (
        light : lighten($black, 10%),
        base  : $black,
        dark  : darken($black, 10%)
    )
);

@function palette($palettes, $palette, $tone: 'base') {
    @return map-get(map-get($palettes, $palette), $tone);
}

$ui-colors: (
  sidebar-close : $white,
  filter-close  : $white,
  search-close  : palette($color-palettes, black, dark)
);

@mixin bg-colors($map) {
  @each $theme-name, $theme in $map {
    &-#{$theme-name} {
      background-color: $theme;
    } 
  }
}

.btn {
  @include bg-colors($ui-colors);
}
```

Css output:

```
.btn-sidebar-close {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.btn-filter-close {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.btn-search-close {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: thanks is this what I am looking for, I just got a small problem I want use another  palette http://pastebin.com/awJXSwBt, so when I print the value comes with palette: .lol-search-close {
  background-color: palette(black, dark);
} , do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Raduken Is `palette` your custom function? Does it returns value from map by key?
Can you paste this function code too?

Comment: sorry, I did edit my quesion, I hope now make more sense, I want use the paletter inside $ui-colors but this return invalid css, make sense now? thank you for your help.

Comment: @Raduken Can you give links to libraries you use?